# Spring data jpa with AWS Lambda

Tags: spring-boot, aws-lambda, spring-data-jpa, aws-api-gateway

Iam new to AWS lambda and trying to create deploy my existing Spring boot with Spring data application in lamda, i have my API endpoints exposed,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "symbols/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
private Symbols getSymbolById(@PathVariable int id) {
    System.err.println("Logged");
    Optional<Symbols> symbol = symbolsRepo.findById(id);
    return symbol != null ? symbol.get() : null;
}
```

And by following the below link, i came to know that, we can deploy our API endpoints in lambda, and using API gateway created with HTTP protocal,

[image]

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-java-container/tree/master/samples/springboot2/pet-store

We can access our endpoint. Iam facing challenges in accessing DB using Spring data jpa. I have done the below configuration,

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: {DB_URL}
    username: {UserName}
    password: {Password}
```

In my local environment it is working, but if i deploy the application by packaging it as zip and deploying it in Lambda, i couldnt able to get the response from API gateway.

Am getting "message": "Service Unavailable" exception

Can anyone let me know, what are the steps to deploy a spring boot application to Lambda?

Also suggest, what programming language we can use, to retrieve data from DB, with Pagination sorting and other features as how Spring Data jpa provides, but can be easier to deploy in lambda.

Comment: Start by checking the Cloudwatch logs.  There is a [quick start](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-java-container/wiki/Quick-start---Spring-Boot) for Lambda/Springboot available too.  For the last question though we need much more details.  Java can do this but Spring and JPA make the solution a bit heavyweight depending on your needs.  If the Lambda is running for 10 minutes then this is fine.  But if it's meant to be a simple single query I would go another route.  Java makes a great Lambda for small things but not with the extra overhead you're describing.

Comment: Is there any example with spring data jpa? I have went throught some articles, and couldnt find

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have hit a bug that has been fixed in the recent AWS Serverless Container 2.0.0 release. We also included test cases for Spring Data JPA now so I strongly suggest to retry with the latest version.